# How is this website blocking requests not made in a browser?

Tags: security, https, webautomation

I'm doing some automation and am trying to make a request for the login page to `https://app.gusto.com/login`. If you navigate there in your browser, that's the first `GET` request that it makes and it responds with the page as expected. However, if you try the exact same^ request anywhere else (curl, Postman, axios), it responds with a `403 Forbidden` error. As far as I understand, at that point (again, it's the first request made) there should be no identifying information at all so it seems like there should be no way for them know that I'm not making the request from a browser. How might they be blocking my request?

^ exact same assuming there's nothing that's missed when you do `Copy > Copy as ...` in the Network tab

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is caused by Cloudflare, the security module the website uses. There's a helpful article about it [here](https://pixeljets.com/blog/scrape-ninja-bypassing-cloudflare-403-code-1020-errors/).